# Can Riven jump over skillshots with her 3rd Q?

Tags: league-of-legends

Riven's 3rd Q launches her into the air briefly, allowing her to leap over thin walls and minions.

Can Riven use her 3rd Q to leap over skillshots like Jinx's Super Mega Death Rocket, Lux's Final Spark, or Veigar's Event Horizon?

Answer (score 6):

No you can't jump **over** a skillshot with riven, however her Q (and E) are still good tools to simply dodge enemy abilities.

In League of Legends you have to differentiate between **blinks** and **dashes**.

Blinks will cause you to be **teleported from point A to B** instantly whereas with a dash you will **travel from point A to B** really quickly.

Since every instance of Riven's Q is a dash in which she remains vulnerable (unlike Maokai W for example), she will get hit by a damaging ability if she tries to pass through it.

It's even possible to knock her out of her animation using a knockup at the right time (Thresh E, Maokai Q), causing her Q to have absolutely no effect while still going on cooldown.

Comment: Is there still some delay in blinking? From what I remember there is a fraction of a second when you blink when your hitboxes are still in the old spot.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer There are some blinks like Ezreal's E for example that have a cast time. If you get hit during the cast time the damage or CC will occur but it's usually only noticeable after you reach your destination. Other than that blinks are instant, although latency can mess around with that.

Answer (score 3):

Riven's Q leap is a displacement, not a blink - so **she will still get snared** by Event Horizon.

As for the other two, I'm not 100% certain but it doesn't make her untargetable, so the Q shouldn't allow to dodge those skillshots without moving away from the line of fire.

Answer (score 0):

Even tho the answer has been already given, I'll add an important thing: **League of Legends is 2D, despite looking 3D!** - This is important for any "jump" ability like Rivens last Q or Tristanas W. The hitbox is still a straight line from the starting point to the arriving point, despite looking like a jump.

The only way to evade such skills are either blinks like Flash or Ezreals E or spells like Maokais W which make you invulnerable for the duration of travel.

Comment: Maokai's W makes him untargetable, not invulnerable.

Comment: @Kruga true, I always mess these up, they are so similar.^^